# Autocomplete Places within Dialog Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am attempting to get a custom Dialog to autocomplete a form field with place names from the Google Places API.

The code I wrote works outside of the Dialog fragment but it gives an obscure error within the dialog (i.e `java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #8: You must supply a layout_height attribute.`)

I've searched around and I think that error is simply the result of a cascade which is caused by something fundamental I have done incorrectly.

Any help would be appreciated and I'll be happy to provide further clarification.

**My custom dialog:**

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_location_picker, null);

    mCityView = (DelayAutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.trip_city);
    mCityView.setAdapter(new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item));
    mCityView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            String[] destination = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().split(",");
            DelayAutoCompleteTextView city = (DelayAutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.trip_city);
            EditText country = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.trip_country);
            city.setText(String.valueOf(destination[0]));
            country.setText(String.valueOf(destination[1]));
        }
    });


    builder.setView(view)
        // Add action buttons
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.confirm_location, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                LocationPickerFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
            }
        });

    return builder.create();
}
```

**My custom autocompleteview:**

```
public class DelayAutoCompleteTextView extends AutoCompleteTextView {
private static final int MESSAGE_TEXT_CHANGED = 100;

private static final int DEFAULT_AUTOCOMPLETE_DELAY = 750;

private int mAutoCompleteDelay = DEFAULT_AUTOCOMPLETE_DELAY;

private ProgressBar mLoadingIndicator;

private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        DelayAutoCompleteTextView.super.performFiltering((CharSequence) msg.obj, msg.arg1);
    }
};

public DelayAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public void setLoadingIndicator(ProgressBar progressBar) {
    mLoadingIndicator = progressBar;
}

public void setAutoCompleteDelay(int autoCompleteDelay) {
    mAutoCompleteDelay = autoCompleteDelay;
}

@Override protected void performFiltering(CharSequence text, int keyCode) {
    if (mLoadingIndicator != null) {
        mLoadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    mHandler.removeMessages(MESSAGE_TEXT_CHANGED);
    mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_TEXT_CHANGED, text), mAutoCompleteDelay);
}

@Override public void onFilterComplete(int count) {
    if (mLoadingIndicator != null) {
        mLoadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    super.onFilterComplete(count);
}
```

}

**My custom places autocomplete adapter:**

```
public class PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {
private ArrayList<String> resultList;

public PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return resultList.size();
}

@Override
public String getItem(int index) {
    return resultList.get(index);
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            if (constraint != null) {
                // Retrieve the autocomplete results.
                resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString());

                // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                filterResults.values = resultList;
                filterResults.count = resultList.size();
            }
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }};
}

private ArrayList<String> autocomplete(String input) {
    ArrayList<String> resultList = null;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
    try {

        URL url = new URL(Config.PLACES_API_BASE + Config.TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + Config.OUT_JSON + "?sensor=false&key=" + Config.GOOGLE_API_KEY + "&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8") + "&types=(cities)");
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

        // Load the results into a StringBuilder
        int read;
        char[] buff = new char[1024];
        while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
            jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e(Config.LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
        return resultList;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(Config.LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
        return resultList;
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }

    try {
        // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
        JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");

        // Extract the Place descriptions from the results
        resultList = new ArrayList<String>(predsJsonArray.length());
        for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
            resultList.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(Config.LOG_TAG, "Cannot process JSON results", e);
    }
    System.out.println("RESPONSE LIST:"+resultList);
    return resultList;
}
```

}

**Where I initialise the dialog from the activity:**

```
mLocationSelect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.trip_location_button);
    mLocationSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DialogFragment locationPicker = new LocationPickerFragment();
            locationPicker.show(getFragmentManager(), null);
        }
    });
```

**The dialog fragment layout:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_place"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:background="#FFFFBB33"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

<com.responseapp.android.ui.common.DelayAutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/trip_city"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:hint="@string/trip_city"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/trip_country"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/trip_country"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"/>
```

Comment: what is line #8 of the layout file of question?

Comment: Of the location_picker fragment it's this: `android:layout_height="64dp"`

Comment: ok,  and what is the full stack trace?

Comment: The full stack trace is here: [https://gist.github.com/samdunne/c00fc88d31076a9dcc47](https://gist.github.com/samdunne/c00fc88d31076a9dcc47)

Comment: the trace suggest that error is in R.layout.list_item xml file,  line #8

Comment: Apologies. Here's that entire file: [https://gist.github.com/samdunne/ee4f35cd303f66d2e900](https://gist.github.com/samdunne/ee4f35cd303f66d2e900)

Comment: ok so for testing purposes replace that ?attr/... with wrap_content or something

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55655/discussion-between-samdunne-and-pskink).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was provided by [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink)

Turns out I needed to change list_item.xml from this:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_dropdown"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textAlignment="inherit"/>
```

To this:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_dropdown"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textAlignment="inherit"/>
```